# how to stub user login for my acceptance tests using capybara , selenium & cucumber

Tags: selenium, authentication, capybara, stub

i am a medium user of cucumber/capybara with selenium & ruby . i am testing the GUI of a portal application where i have to login for every test before going to other steps. i feel it is time consuming to see the user login for every test before going thru further pages. is there a way to stub the login so that i can start off with the logged in screen directly? i have searched the net and there is some info like warden helpers which i dont think can be applied to my case as it is not a rails-application( i am not sure what is a rails application, i am a tester). as far as i understand , the warden helpers are used when you use devise authentication which i think is more relevant to a developer developing a rails application. my company buys portlets from another company and then develops the web application further. The way i login right now is find the elements on the page and fill in the fields using capybara with selenium webdriver like below. i use these steps for everything test in my cucumber scenarios.

```
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.default_driver =:selenium
visit 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080'
click_button('signIn')
fill_in('#email',:with=>'xyz@gmail.com')
fill_in('#password',:with=>'abcd')
click_button('signIn')
```

please let  me know if there is a way ...and apologies if my question is a basic one.

Comment: what i mean stubbing here is , i want the login to happen before the browser starts so that my visual verification of the test starts after the login screen. for ex, if i want to add a user , i have to login to the site as admin first and then goto administration section and add user. i wanted a logic using capybara/cucumber in ruby that i see directly the admin section page with user already logged in. please let me know if it is possible

Comment: Just because "I am a tester" doesn't mean you can gain knowledge ;) Your best bet is to understand how the application "logs in" and how it keeps session. For instance, some applications expose the login service via an API call which would return a cookie. Providing you retain that cookie, it is proof of your session which you can use going forward.

Comment: Hi Arran, the reason I said 'I am a tester' is because the device gem is basically for someone who is developing a rails application.Being a tester , I dont decide the authentication process , so if BDD /TDD is not followed, I have to use to whatever authentication is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. It looks like when you use a browser instance in your tests like below , the user stays logged in already as you are still in the same session. 
For example i put this in my env.rb

```
 browser = Capybara.default_driver =:selenium

 Before do
 @browser = browser
 end

 at_exit do
 @browser
 end
```

By doing this the user stays login and now I dont put login steps for every test but only once in the start for a single feature. And for every test , i just visit the login url , when the browser loads it , the user is already logged in. The tests are now a lot faster than before.